# Android not getting right photo from gallery

Tags: android, imageview, gallery, onactivityresult

I am implementing a pick photo from gallery and then show it in a ImageView. I had the some issues  and, thanks to this solution: [Null Intent passed back on Samsung](https://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/null-intent-passed-back-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/), is partially solved. I can take the photo and it's saved in a custom location:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (Helpers.isExternalStorageWritable()) {
    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Globals.Constants.APP_NAME);
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmm").format(new Date());
    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "report" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(imageIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

However when in onActivityResult, when I show the taken picture in a ImageView, I got a random photo from my old photos. Here's my onActivityResult code:

```
try {
Log.i("TAG", "inside Samsung Phones");
String[] projection = {
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, // The columns we want
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA };
String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + "=" + MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND;
String sort = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC";
Cursor myCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, sort);
long imageId = 0l;
long thumbnailImageId = 0l;
String thumbnailPath = "";

try {
    myCursor.moveToFirst();
    imageId = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));
    thumbnailImageId = myCursor.getLong(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));
    thumbnailPath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));
} finally {
    // myCursor.close();
}
String[] largeFileProjection = {
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };
String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID + " DESC";
myCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);
String largeImagePath = "";

try {
    myCursor.moveToFirst();
    largeImagePath = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
    mImageCaptureUri_samsung = Uri.fromFile(new File(largeImagePath));
    mImageCaptureUri = null;
} finally {
    // myCursor.close();
}

Uri uriLargeImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(imageId));
Uri uriThumbnailImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(thumbnailImageId));

 image1.setImageURI(uriThumbnailImage);
}
```

Another issue is that the .thumbnail neither the actual photo are shown right away, it takes a couple minutes to be shown in the gallery or file manager. But now I would be happy if anyone can help me with the random picture shown. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: `a pick photo from gallery`. Ok. `take the photo`. If you take a photo you use the camera and make a new foto. If you pick a photo from gallery you pick an existing photo. You are unclear in what you want and mix it all up.

Comment: The whole thing of using EXTRA_OUTPUT with uriSavedImage is that you later use uriSavedImage in onActivityResult to get the file.

Comment: Hi @greenapps, this is exactly what Kevin says in his post. The pick photo from gallery is a workaround for some Samsung devices (I'm developing on Galaxy Note 4), and when I implement the default onActionResult callback, it returns data = null. So maybe you should check (https://kevinpotgieter.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/null-intent-passed-back-on-samsung-galaxy-tab/ ) to understand the situation.

Comment: `I can take the photo and it's saved in a custom location:`. If that is true then i do not understand why you just don't use that custom location. You have not explained why you do not use it. Of course i will not look at all those links as i expect you to post a clear story here.

Comment: Hi @greenapps, I tried before what you suggested but I don't know why the **just taken photo** doesn't appear in the folder right away, it takes a couple seconds before it show. So when I tried to retrieve the image, the file doesn't exist. Maybe it's a bug or another Sammy glitch.